# Compare two Excel workbooks for differences and copy/paste all the information from one to another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

On some difficult issue I am bumped in. And i guess it quite out of my knowledge, and I hope it is even possible to solve on some way.

**ISSUE:**

Two different workbooks: I am having one workbook with 10 sheets inside, with many formulas, dropdowns, calculations etc., and it is main version of the document which has to be filled with information.

Second workbook, or better to say another similar version to this workbook is like obsolete versions of main wb, where might be possible that some cells/format, or even sheet is missing, but in general almost the same from its structure.

**PROCESS:**

Sometimes the customers are not having the newest version of excel workbook, but still some of the obsolete versions (they are forgetting to use the newest version), and they are filling those fields inside those older versions and sending them back. The problem is, our ERP Software cant read the obsolete versions, because it is so adjusted to read only the newest version of the document. Meaning, it has to be manually checked every time when the document is sent back and finding  discrepancies and copy/paste them into newest version of the document, and then upload it into ERP...

**RESULT:**

I am looking for some solution, with VBA or even formulas how to check every other workbook against "newest" and if there are any discrepancy and differences just to copy/paste everything from old to new version. When I say "everything" it means, all the fields, sheets, calculations, 1:1.

Unfortunately I am not writing any code or formula, because this is for me super advanced.

On the pic below is one example of one sheet how it looks like. There are lot of columns, calcs and so on.

**Explanation:**

To clarify bit better the content: inside one workbook is usually 10 sheets. 8x of them are the same (gas chambers from 1-8) and depending on the customer wishes, they can populated from 1-8. Sometimes 1 sometimes 5.
And range is from A1:Q54, full of data, tables, calculations, dropdowns, infos..

One sheet (9th) is customer details and last one (10th) is just instruction sheet with infos and screenshots.

So optimal would be to have macro that is taking everything from older versions, compare it with new one, and populate data that it finds, or on already given workbook or on new one but with the same content. I dont know if that is something possible.

[image]

Comment: In principle, use a macro to scrape the user entered data from the old format worksheets into a 3 column table ( sheet name, cell address, value ) and then apply mapping rules to fill a new format template with those values.

Comment: @CDP1802 Easily said...but in practice aint that easy. I uploaded one SS just to have feeling with what kind of data I am dealing of.

Comment: Are the other 9 sheets similar ? What does a new sheet look like ?

Comment: @CDP1802 From 10 sheets, 8x of them are the same as this one that is uploaded. Another one is instructions sheet and last is like some customer details sheet.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to scan various cell ranges in a workbook and collate those that have values into a table. Second stage would be to transfer those values to the new format template.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub extractAll()

    Dim myfile As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, msg As String
    
    ' select workbook to scan
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Please select a file"
        .Show
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
            MsgBox "You did not select a file"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        myfile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    ' collate data on sheet 1 and 2
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    Sheet1.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Sheet", "Addr", "Row", "Column", "Value")
    Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range("A2")
    
    Sheet2.Cells.Clear
    Sheet2.Range("A1:D1") = Array("Addr", "Row", "Column", "Value")
    Set rng2 = Sheet2.Range("A2")
    ' open workbook and scan worksheets
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfile, ReadOnly:=True)
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "CH_recipe_#" Then
            Call scanSheet(ws, rng1)
            msg = msg & vbLf & ws.Name
        ElseIf ws.Name = "Customer Details" Then
            Call scanCustomer(ws, rng2)
            msg = msg & vbLf & ws.Name
        End If
    Next
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    MsgBox "Sheets scanned" & msg
    
End Sub

Sub scanSheet(ws As Worksheet, ByRef rng As Range)
 
    Dim cell As Range, ar, s As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    ' old template layout
    s = "D13,A15,C15,D15,E15,G15,J15,N15," ' process details
    s = s & "E20:P24,E41:P41," ' Carrier, Gas 2-12, usage
    s = s & "C45,D45,E45,G45,I45,K45,M45,N45,P45," ' exhaust line
    s = s & "C48" ' notes and remarks

    ar = Split(s, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
        For Each cell In ws.Range(ar(i))
           If cell.Value <> "" Then
                rng = ws.Name
                rng.Offset(, 1) = cell.Address(0, 0)
                rng.Offset(, 2) = cell.Row
                rng.Offset(, 3) = cell.Column
                rng.Offset(, 4) = cell.Value
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
           End If
        Next
    Next

    Debug.Print ws.Name & " Done"
End Sub


Sub scanCustomer(ws As Worksheet, ByRef rng As Range)
 
    Dim cell As Range, ar, s As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    ' old template layout
    s = "B14:B25," ' contact details
    s = s & "B28:B29," ' existing install
    s = s & "B32:B35," ' hook up
    s = s & "A38" ' remarks

    ar = Split(s, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
        For Each cell In ws.Range(ar(i))
           If cell.Value <> "" Then
                rng = cell.Address(0, 0)
                rng.Offset(, 1) = cell.Row
                rng.Offset(, 2) = cell.Column
                rng.Offset(, 3) = cell.Value
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
           End If
        Next
    Next

    Debug.Print ws.Name & " Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: I will test it tomorrow. I cant access now the rest of test files. So as I see it, I am putting this code into my "main" WB and then activating Macro for another WBs for scanning? 
So If I understand code correctly, I am having my main WB opened and with Macro I will be populating everything (info's) from another excel files (in my case older versions) into this main WB?

Comment: Yes, copy the code into a new blank workbook, save it as Reformatter.xlsm (for example). Running the extractAll macro will open a file selection dialog where you can choose the old format file. It will then copy all the data onto sheet1 of this Reformatter workbook. This is just the proof of concept stage. Another macro (to be developed) would open a blank template and copy the data back into the new layout.

Comment: So, I tried but it seems it is not as it should be. Let me update a bit more infos about WB and content. I also updated my Question above.
8x Sheets are the same, these are like specific gas chambers, and it is optional if someone will add 1,2 or all 8. And inside there are many infos, calculations which also need to be taken over once macro is running.

Comment: @Mirza Are the same calculations not done in the new format workbook ?. The variable number of gas chambers would not be a problem.

Comment: Yes they are...as I say the wb are 90% the same...but as I saw in coding it is starting from Column C...actually it has to be in this array A1:Q54. Or I am not understanding maybe how you imagined on second step of Macro when it is gonna copy/paste the data....

Comment: @Mirza Your screen shot doesn't show column name or row  number so I was guessing C5,D5,E5,G5,J5,N5,C7 would be the green cells on the first 2 lines starting with Tool Manufacturer, Tool Model,  etc

Comment: Check now the Screenshot..I updated it. And also in that "blank" space from row 25 to 35 i think, it is formula based cells, thats a reason its hidden. Depending on drop down that red marked on A15

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241782/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-mirza).